# how to convey the coordinate from didUpdateLocation to some view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am trying to make `LocationService` class that will convey userCoordinate, so it will be reusable for more than one View Controller

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class LocationService: NSObject {
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()

        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func getPermission() {
        // to ask permission to the user by showing an alert (the alert message is available on info.plist)
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func checkLocationAuthorizationStatus() -> CLAuthorizationStatus{
        return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    }
}

extension LocationService : CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            manager.requestLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("location is not available: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        guard let userLocation = locations.first else {return}

        if userLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            let coordinate = Coordinate(location: userLocation)
            // how to convey this coordinate for several view controller?
        } 
    }
}
```

as you can see in the `didUpdateLocations` method that comes from `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, the coordinate need some time to be generated.

but I don't know how to convey that user coordinate, I think it will use completion handler but I don't know how to get that

so let say in HomeVC, I will call that `LocationService` to get the userCoordinate

```
import UIKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    let locationService = LocationService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // get coordinate, something like this
       locationService.getCoordinate()
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably use a `Notification`, then any interested objects can simply listen for that notification and obtain the location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Notification` like Paulw11 said. You need to update `didUpdateLocations`. This is the place where you are going to post notification.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let userLocation = locations.first else {return}

    if userLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        let coordinate = Coordinate(location: userLocation)
        let locationDictionary: [String: Double] = ["lat": location.coordinate.latitude,
                                      "long": location.coordinate.longitude]
         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "YourNotificationNameAsYouWantToNameIt"), object: nil, userInfo: locationDictionary)
    } 
}
```

Now in `viewDidLoad` in every view controller that you want this location you need to observe this notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doSomethingAboutLocation(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "YourNotificationNameAsYouWantToNameIt"), object: nil)
```

Then access your location like this in your function called from selector:

```
@objc func doSomethingAboutLocation(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let notificationInfo = notification.userInfo {
       let coordinate = CLLocation(latitude: notificationInfo["lat"] as! Double, longitude: notificationInfo["long"] as! Double)
       // use your coordinate as you want
    }
}
```